# its not navigating to the class

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I am writing the following code in a button click event and i am trying to navigato the class PDFReaderViewController, but on click of the button its not navigating, can anybody tell me y

```
UINavigationController *addNavigationController;
PDFReaderViewController *avController = [[PDFReaderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    if(addNavigationController == nil)
{
        addNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:avController];
    addNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    addNavigationController.navigationBar.alpha=0.7f;
    addNavigationController.navigationBar.translucent=YES;


    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:addNavigationController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are actually looking for?
In your code you are trying to present a navigationController from another navigation controller.

To present a vieController as a modelViewController you don't need a custom NavigationController.You can present it simply by:

```
PDFReaderViewController *avController = [[PDFReaderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:avController animated:YES];
[avController release];
```

Comment: Thanx for ur reply , i have tried that too but its not navigating to that class, nothing is happening  on click of the button,,its navigating with this code PDFReaderViewController *objPDFReaderViewController = [[PDFReaderViewController alloc]init];
   [self presentModalViewController:objPDFReaderViewController animated:YES];
   [objPDFReaderViewController release];,,,but it ill not create navigation bar on the top

Comment: It works only if your current viewController has a navigation controller.

Comment: If you don't have any navigation stack there then you have to initialize on and present ViewController from it like: UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller];[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
    [navController release];

Comment: now its navigating but title bar(navigation bar) is not coming in that class(i.e in  PDFReaderViewController  class) can u tell me how can i fix this

Comment: In which class you miss the navigationBar?The presented viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

```
Class *obj=[Class alloc];

[self.view addSubview:obj.view];
```

You can use this for navigating Class.